# New non clustered index throws deadlocks

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012, deadlock

I have a mvc application with entity framework. Recently I was suggested by the MSSQL server to create an new non clustered index in a table on a foreign key and including a date column.

I decided to create it, due to performance issues.

Indexed created with allow_page_blocks and allow_row_block set to on.

The performance significally got better, but I have many deadlocks now.

I was suggested by forums to convert it from non-clustered to clustered, but I can't 'cause an index cant 'include' date columns.

Any other suggestion?

Comment: You should analyse why the deadlocks are occurring rather than throwing indexes at it. Is this table frequently updated or selected?

Comment: Before I added the index I had no deadlocks. And yes the table has many read/writes. It's the base table of my app

Comment: A clustered index kind-of _already_ includes all columns (in a manner of speaking). Clustered indexes really help if you are ordering data or if you are searching on a range. You will need to provide much more info for anyone to be of help. There are no details in your question. How many records? Is it just one part of your application that causes the deadlocks? What does the application do? There might be better ways to do things. Maybe you are doing work in the application layer that should be done in the database.

Comment: It would also really help to link the forum where you got this information from

Comment: Admittedly I am surprised you added a index on the FK before having a clustered index on the PK? (Natural or ID)